# Why both netbeans and eclipse force JSP and TAG files to be ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, netbeans, utf-8, tags

Nobody in the whole world, in these many years of java web development, had this issue?
(I hardly think so)

How to deal with that?

I prefer all (really all) of my sources in UTF8

Comment: I already know this solution <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: So, what's the question? Eclipse and Netbeans don't force any encoding, and you already know how to use UTF-8.

Comment: My question is why (as the title's text), maybe I'm doing something wrong, or it's an inevitable situation. My need is to be clear

Answer (score 1):

The default for Eclipse is to encode JSP files as ISO-8859-1 (as for the reason why that is the default, I do not know for sure).

You can change the default encoding used when creating a JSP files (and other files) in Eclipse. Open the preferences dialog (Window > Preferences menu item), then search for encoding.

For existing files in a project, open the files in Eclipse and use the Edit > Set Encoding menu item.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse, it's because of JavaServer Pages™ Specification Version 2.2, Maintenance Release 2, Appendix D, sections 1.3g and 2.1c.